# Gaussian Random Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian, bivariate-distributions

I have a random process,
$$Y_i=Bf_i+W_i,\quad i=0,\ldots,N$$

The RVs $B,W_1,\ldots,W_n$ are i.i.d., with $B\thicksim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_b^2)$ and $W_i\thicksim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_w^2)$.  The function $f_i$ is a known deterministic signal.

I am trying to determine the joint Gaussian for $Y_i$.  I can see that $\mu_{\mathbf{y}}$ is $\mathbf{0}$, but I cannot get straight in my mind what the covariance matrix, $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is....

... I am anticipating covariance components in the non-diagonal elements of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ because if $B$ is slightly higher, then $Y_i$ will shift higher and $\textit{vice versa}$.

Comment: hint: compute $E(Y_i , Y_j )$ explicitly.

Comment: I am getting $f_i^2\sigma_b^2+\sigma_w^2$ by simulation.  I can get this from $f_i\mathrm{var}(B)+\mathrm{var}(W)_i$.  These two reconcile... I cannot see how to express $E(Y_i,Y_j)$... Also, I am led to understand that $Y_i$ is dependant on $B$, so I was expecting some type of covariance... totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E(Y_i) =0$ the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{ij} = E(Y_i Y_j)$. Writing explicitly: $E(Y_i Y_j) = E(B^2 f_i f_j + W_i W_j +B W_i f_i +B W_j f_j)$.

Note that $B,W_j$ are uncorrelated, leaving us with $E(B^2 f_i f_j + W_i W_j)$. Now consider the case $i=j$ versus $i\neq j$ and also recall that $f$ are deterministic. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, ok.  Wow.  I might have to revisit my simulation... but taking the mathematics forward, I think it might be $\Sigma_{ii}=f_i^2\sigma_b^2+\sigma_{w}^2$ for $i=j$ and $\Sigma_{ij}=f_if_j\sigma_b^2+\sigma_{w_i}\sigma_{w_j}=f_if_j\sigma_b^2+\sigma_w^2$ for $i\neq j$

Comment: Note that the $W$ are uncorrelated when $i \neq j$

Comment: Thankyou user619894.  I have learned something here.